# Uncaught TypeError: http.createServer is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I use `http.createServer` in `node.js` the following error occured.

```
Uncaught TypeError: http.createServer is not a function
```

the code of server.js is given below

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');

function start(route) {
  var onRequest = function (request, response) {
    route(request, response);
  };

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log('Server has started');
}

exports.start = start;
```

Comment: All working here when I pasted your code into a new file and called start() with a function. @PraveenKumar, `http` is a native module.

Comment: @ev0lution Just found it. Sorry. LoL. And yeah, the code works well for me too! `:/`

Comment: Can you try using a fresh installation? How are you running the application?